# How to loop a jmeter request?

Tags: jmeter

I have a request `https://***********/projects?page=1`

which gives the response

```
 {
    "QueryInfo": {
      "QryNa": "Q_PTE1",
      "resourc": "https://******************QueryResultsAsXML.v2/q/?auth=",
      "CurrentPage": "page=1",
      "FirstPage": "page=1",
      "LastPage": "page=6",
      "Rows": "1000",
      "TotalRows": "6000"
    } 
}
```

I have to verify the LastPage, if it's more than 1 I have to run the same above request for all Pages numbers from 1 to 6. I have captured the page number in regular expression. Can you tell how to loop for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Add an [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with condition `${__jexl3("${LastPage}" > 1)}` where `LastPage` is the reference name for your regular expression extractor.

Add a [loop controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and change the loop count to `${__intSum(${LastPage},-1)}`

Add a [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) under the loop controller with below configurations

- Start: `2`
- Increment: `1`
- Maximum: `${LastPage}`
- Reference Name: `pageCounter`
- Make sure to check both `Track counter independently for each user` & `Reset counter on each Thread Group iteration`

Copy & paste your HTTP request under the loop controller and change `page` parameter to `page=${pageCounter}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above response and configure it like:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `lastPage`
   - Regular expression: `"LastPage"\s?:\s?"page=(\d+)",`
   - Template: `$1$`
2. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) after the request and use the following condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('lastPage') as int) > 1,)}
   ```
3. [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) as a child of the If Controller and use the following expression as the "Loop Count":

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('lastPage') as int) -1,)}
   ```
4. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as a child of the Loop Controller and amend the request body to look like:

   ```
   {
     "QueryInfo": {
       "QryNa": "Q_PTE1",
       "resourc": "https://******************QueryResultsAsXML.v2/q/?auth=",
       "CurrentPage": "page=${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},2,)}",
       "FirstPage": "page=1",
       "LastPage": "page=6",
       "Rows": "1000",
       "TotalRows": "6000"
     }
   }
   ```

   [image]